# Adding role=document to div causes JAWS to read "clickable"

Tags: html, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

I'm working on an application that displays a list of chats and need to get the chats into the virtual buffer. The chat content can be as simple as a line of text or as complicated as text plus a link plus an image. Without `role=document`, it's not in the buffer but with `role=document` JAWS reads "clickable" when it reads the content (after pressing down arrow). The content is not clickable and I can't figure out how to stop that from being read.

Here's an example of the layout:

```html
<div role="application" class="mainViewContainer">
  <ul class="mainViewContent">
    <li tabindex="0" class="chatViewContainer">
      <div tabindex="-1" class="chatHeaderContainer">
        <span class="offscreen" id="chat1">Chat content</span>
        <div role="document" tabindex="0" class="chatContent" aria-labelledby="chat1">
          Here's a message, huzzah!
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0" class="chatViewContainer">
      <div tabindex="-1" class="chatHeaderContainer">
        <span class="offscreen" id="chat2">Chat content</span>
        <div role="document" tabindex="0" class="chatContent" aria-labelledby="chat2">
          <div class="chatText>Document <a href="/link/artifact=12121">documentName.jpg</a> created </div>
          <div class="documentView">
            <img title="documentName.jpg" src="imgsrc">
            <div class="documentItemDetails">
              <a href="/link/artifact=12121&viewMode=EXPANDED" class="documentName">documentName.jpg</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to make the `chatContent` div not have "clickable" read by JAWS?

I'm seeing this with JAWS Version 15.0.6025 (I believe it's the most recent version) and FF 26 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. Apparently, this is an expected behavior, as explained in [this URL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17984_01/doc.898/e14710/jde_e1_accessibility_jaws.htm).

> **Clickable Text :** When you navigate to a grid cell that has its display style set to clickable text, JAWS reads the corresponding column header text and then the data content of the current cell.

I hope this helps.